# "Content-Encoding: gzip" HTTP response header unity webgl error

Tags: c#, unity-webgl

I keep on getting this error and don't know what to do. Please help!

Unable to parse Build/WebGL.framework.js.gz! This can happen if build compression was enabled but web server hosting the content was misconfigured to not serve the file with HTTP Response Header "Content-Encoding: gzip" present. Check browser Console and Devtools Network tab to debug.

BTW i"m using Firefox

[image: Error]

I can't find anything that will help me, and I tried reading documentation, but nothing!

Comment: please tell me you found it